Can the GOP replace the VP after the convention?
Does the GOP provide a path to replace the VP AFTER the convention? What happens if the VP steps down? What happens if the president no longer wishes to run with the VP he choose?

There have been previous questions about replacing the Presidential nominee after the convention. It would be very surprising if the process for VP were any different.

@Barmar idk. A lack of a Presidential nominee can lead to a constitutional crisis. A lack of a VP nominee is much less so, and there is an express constitutional provision for filling VP vacancies between Presidential elections.

@ohwilleke There's nothing in the Constitution about politial parties, I don't see how it can be a crisis if one of the parties doesn't have a nominee. You just vote for some other candidate. If, somehow, there were no candidates, that would be a crisis.

I don't know how much of a dupe asking VP procedures is.  After all, primary voters vote for a POTUS candidate (whose choice gets "materialized" at the convention).  Not a VP - who often get announced quite late in/after the primary cycle.  So a change does not carry the same impact of ignoring those voters' choice.  Maybe it's the same, maybe it's not, but I would not be very surprised if it were not.

@Barmar I don't see how that is a duplicate as the procedure for choosing the republican presidential and vice presidential are completely different.  The presidential nominee is chosen by a vote of all the delegates at the convention while the vice presidential nominee is chosen solely by the presidential nominee and the RNC or convention don't have the say in who is chosen though they likely are providing some input. The could be a simple matter of the presidential nominee choosing someone else or state election laws could make it more complicated.

@JoeW Did you read the answer there? The procedure is stated to be for both candidates.

@Barmar In a two party system who else would you vote for? If one of the parties doesn't have a candidate.

@JoeW There's nothing constitutional about the two-party system. There are always other parties on the ballot, they just don't usually get enough votes to matter. If one of the major parties dropped out of the race, I guess they'll become more important.

@Barmar You seem to be missing my point, the convention doesn't have anything to do with the vice presidential nomination as it is a decision that is solely made by the presidential nomination. They could even wait to announce who was chosen until after the convention if they so chose to.

@JoeW That's not how I understand it. The RNC nominates both candidates. The VP is usually just a rubber stamp of the running mate that the POTUS candidate selected, but I'm not sure that's in the official process.

@Barmar And the last time a third party has gotten an electoral college vote was in 1968 but even that had no impact on the outcome of the election as Nixon had enough votes to win even if Humphry had gotten all of the electoral college votes that the third party Wallace had. It is great to say that we have third party choices but they have no real impact on the election besides stealing a few votes from both sides.

@JoeW Of course, because there's never been an election without a candidate from both parties. And there never will, since the parties have processes in place to replace the nominee if something happens after the convention. This is all totally theoretical.

@Barmar Then you have a misunderstanding on it, the presidential nominee has full control over who the vice presidential nominee is and at most the RNC would be a rubber stamp.

@Barmar And you don't see that it happening wouldn't be a major issue? The fact that one of the parties that would receive a major percentage of the votes wouldn't get a say in the election? If one party was left of that would make it impossible for about half of the country to have their voices heard.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Barmar I  don't see the need to continue it there and will pass.

@JoeW Yes, it's a huge issue, but not a "constitutional crisis", since nothing about this process is in the constitution. You're not losing your right to have your voices heard if your candidate drops out of the race and the party doesn't replace them. But that would never actually happen, the party will replace them.

I tend to think it's a duplicate as well. The TL;DR is this part The Republican National Committee is hereby authorized and empowered to fill any and all vacancies which may occur by reason of death, declination, or otherwise of the Republican candidate for President of the United States or the Republican candidate for Vice President of the United States, as nominated by the national convention, or the Republican National Committee may reconvene the national convention for the purpose of filling any such vacancies.
